# Define webroot path in PHP

Tags: php

I want to define a constant that refer to the webroot of my application.

The

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

is not good for me because that return me `C:\wamp\www` without the project name.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This indicates a configuration error that should be fixed, not paved over with a constant. Each application should have its own web root, and it **should not** be overly broad so as to allow access to anything outside of the necessary files. Keep your exposed "document root" as tiny as possible, and avoid including *any* credentials whatsoever in those files.

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like you are using the basic WAMP setup with your projects in www. I assume you access it using http://localhost/project-name. If this is the case you should set up a separate virtual host per project which would then set the DOCUMENT_ROOT. I've not use WAMP in a million years so can't verify the information on this site but have a look at https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/ for some pointers.

Comment: just `var_dump($_SERVER)` and follow. You said `find a generic way that work on several project with different names ` then I am sorry but using wamp is not good. You have to setup a proper server env like debian, create your app, and then later port it to windows.